# kendo ui for vue, how can i use both row-render and rowclick

Tags: vue.js, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/blissful-tdd-5g4x7w?file=%2Fsrc%2Fmain.vue

when i use row-render, rowclick event is not working ...
but cellclick event is working

i use print method for emit parental component ( in my real grid component)

```
      console.log(event);
      let target = event.event.target;

      if (
        target.className.includes &&
        !(
          target.className.includes('input') ||
          target.className.includes('button')
        )
      ) {
        console.log(event);
        this.$emit('rowSelected', event.dataItem);
      }
    },
```

i found another way to fix my component
but it need to change return value..
like event.dataItem,

please help me